# Firefox "secure connection failed" error, xpath.alephzarro

Tags: firefox

I keep getting this error periodically:

[image]

Wondering if I have some malware installed. Has anyone seen this before? How do I get rid of it?

---

### Enabled addons:

- Adblock Plus
- Download Statusbar
- Firebug
- Greasemonkey
- Status-4-Evar
- Tab Mix Plus
- Xmarks
- JSONView

Going to try disabling JSONView first because I use that one the least.....and hopefully that was the bugger.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your computer, it is the site `xpath.alephzarro.com` that has got a bad certificate for their https security setup. The [HTTP Secure](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Https) (https) protocol requires that the website present a valid certificate issued by a known authority.

The certificate that is used was issued by realtime.sk, which is not a known [Certificate authority](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA), and no [certificate chain](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc/sy10600_.htm) could be established to a known certificate authority.

If you are in anyway affiliated with this site, you could ask them to get themselves a certificate issued by a known authority, even if this costs a few dollars.

Comment: Well the popup says that much, but why is it coming up? On any site that I visit? It's not like I'm viewing their site and it's popping up, it just pops up randomly as I'm surfing the web, which means *something* is trying to access that site. Which made me suspicious that my information is being sent to them. Either that, or something is being requested from them. Either way, other people don't seem to experiencing this issue, so something's gotta be up. I'll list my addons when I get home, but it's mostly standard stuff... Greasemonkey, Tab mix plus, Firebug, xmarks maybe?

Comment: Do you mean that this is coming up when you are not viewing xpath.alephzarro.com ? This site contains a FF add-on called XPather, which seems to be last compatible with FF 3.6. Do you have add-on compatibility check on? Have you tried running "Mozilla Firefox (Safe Mode)" ?

Comment: Correct. That is exactly what I mean. I didn't install any addon called XPather...can addons include other addons? I'll have to check if add-on compatibility is on... I think so, because FF7 disabled some of my old ones. Will try Safe Mode what I get home, but if it goes away, it's still not really solving the issue.

Comment: An add-on can do whatever it feels like doing. If in Safe Mode the problem goes away, you will have to turn off extensions and plugins until you find the guilty one, then uninstall it.